# Find link from webpage using selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

I am working on selenium java. I wrote java code for Automation testing for google search and requirement is find link from webpage that is given into excel sheet and click on that link on webpage.so i am getting all links from webpage but not able to click on provided link from excel sheet.

```
                        List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
                      int linkcount=allLinks.size();
                      System.out.println("All Links :" +linkcount);
                    
                      for(int j=0 ;j<linkcount;j++ )
                       {
                        String ele= driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(j).getText();
                         
                        System.out.println(ele);
                        if(ele.equals(Expected))
                        {
                              allLinks.get(j).click();
                            
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should work , make sure that String equals condition is evaluating to true or not there might be spaces in the Expected URL String which may lead to condition evaluating to false

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        int linkcount = allLinks.size();
        System.out.println("All Links :" + linkcount);
        for (int j = 0; j < linkcount; j++) {
            WebElement element =allLinks.get(j);
            String actualURL = element.getText(); 
            System.out.println("Actual URL is: "+actualURL);
            if (actualURL.equals(expectedURL)) {
                allLinks.get(j).click();
                break;
                //break once found
            }
        }
```